# How to echo the_excerpt without the P tag wrapper?

Tags: plugin-development

In the code snippet below, I trying to get the_excerpt to be written out without tags. However, the source formatting shows that the_excerpt is always wrapped in P tags. How can I pull the excerpt without tags?

```
foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post) 
{ ?>
<li class="page_item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php echo strip_tags(substr( the_excerpt(), 0, 75 ))."..." ?>
</li><?php }    
echo "</ul>
</div>";}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

in your code above use `get_the_excerpt()` instead of `the_excerpt()`, because the last one will output the excerpt to the screen, and not pass it to your other functions...

Answer (score 7):

What about removing the `wpautop` filter before your list?

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

(Make sure to add it back afterwards, so as not to mess up other formatting...)

Comment: This is the correct answer and will specifically remove the formatting on the particular page that you are using to output the content.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above answers but didn't work for me.

I tried using the_excerpt but wasn't displaying any content so I used the below and it worked perfectly

```
// $search_text = the_excerpt();
$search_text = get_the_excerpt();

// Strip the <p> tag by replacing it empty string
$tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
$search_content = str_replace($tags, "", $search_text);

// Echo the content

echo $search_content;
```

I hope this throws more light for someone else too.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>`this worked for me

sorry for this => Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 18.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/260326)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want `<p>` tags when using `the_excerpt()`, you can use `echo get_the_excerpt()` instead, which strip `<p>` tags.

If you also want to make sure that you remove linebreaks and whitespace you can use `echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true );`.

Using `get_the_excerpt`, might cause an undefined offset -1, then you need to check first with `has_excerpt()`.

Answer (score -1):

Below did the trick using ACF plugin:

```
<p>
    <?php
        $summary = get_field('introductory_text');
        echo strip_tags(substr($summary, 0, 520));
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> ...read more</a>
</p>
```